# How to retrieve data using postgresql using only html5 and angular js?

Tags: angularjs, html

My problem is that I have to search inputs as  id , date of joining and by entering and submitting those values the data should be retrieved from pgadmin3 (postgresql) and should display as pdf or as table in browser. for example: date of joining is my search term by searching that term in postgres in which already all attributes are dumped and should display that in browser...so please send me any links or step by step procedure to do with that using only html5 and angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this isn't possible through pure HTML5 and AngularJS as you will need some back-end technology for the actual querying of the Postgres database.

As a beginner I suggest starting at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/). It contains a lot of information on HTML, CSS and AngularJS.

W3Schools also contains information on different server side technology's which can be used to query your Postgres database.

SQL will be used as the querying technology on a database, although Postgres does have it's own flavor of SQ,L and the basics can be picked up from W3Schools.